# Does calling interrupt() on a thread create happens-before relation with the interrupted thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

In other words I want to know if changing variable before interrupt is always visible when interrupt is detected inside interrupted thread. E.g.

```java
private int sharedVariable;

public static void interruptTest() {
    Thread someThread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Is it here guaranteed that changes before interrupt are always visible here?
            System.out.println(sharedVariable);
        }
    });
    someThread.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    sharedVariable = 10;
    someThread.interrupt();
}
```

I tried to find answer in [Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) and in 
[Summary page of the java.util.concurrent package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) mentioned in [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) but `interrupt` was not mentioned.

I know about `volatile` and other synchronize primitives but do I need them?

Comment: I haven't been able to find the information except in "Java Concurrency in Practice" (See Interruption rule in http://what-when-how.com/Tutorial/topic-355vueju/Java-Concurrency-in-Practice-417.html). But i's the bible, so it's most probably correct. It would be nice if @BrianGoetz confirmed, and explained why it's not in the javadoc/JLS (unless I missed it, of course).

Comment: If i were to rephrase the question, you are effectively asking if by calling Thread.interrupt(), one could guarantee that the latest state of "sharedVariable" be used from within "someThread" without using the documented ways of achieving happens-before and sharing state(using locks, atomic variables or volatile). And the answer to that would be no. So yes, i think you would need to make it volatile or use locking.

Comment: @jay - interruption _is_ a [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4) way of establishing _happens-before_.

Comment: @BeeOnRope thank you for pointing it out. Agreed that the interruption of thread T2 by T1 has a happens before relationship between them. But does that guarantee a happens before between the lines "sharedVariable = 10" and "someThread.interrupt()"? Due to a lack of synchronised-with mechanism between those 2 lines, i'm still inclined to think that OP requires to make "sharedVariable" volatile or use locking.

Comment: Yes, there is a happens before relationship between each statement in source order, such as between `sharedVariable = 10;` and `someThread.interrupt();` above. Otherwise, happens-before would pretty useless, it wouldn't guarantee anything about the _rest_ of the code, and those are the guarantees you want. A typical example is setting all the fields of an object during construction, then _publishing_ that object via a `volatile` reference. Another thread reading the `volatile` reference is guaranteed that all the fields are also set. Without this _everything_ would need to be volatile!

Comment: @jay - the exact text in the JLS that guarantees this is also from 17.4.5, although I clipped it out in my quote below. It is _If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y)._  Here's the [direct link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5-110-A).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, interrupting a thread T2 from a thread T1 creates a *happens-before* relationship between T1 and T2, as described in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4) **17.4.4. Synchronization Order**:

> If thread T1 interrupts thread T2, the interrupt by T1
>   synchronizes-with any point where any other thread (including T2)
>   determines that T2 has been interrupted (by having an
>   InterruptedException thrown or by invoking Thread.interrupted or
>   Thread.isInterrupted).

Now that only implies that T1 *synchronizes-with* the detection of the interrupt T2, while you asked about *happens-before*. Luckily the former implies the latter from **17.4.5. Happens-before Order**:

> Two actions can be ordered by a happens-before relationship. If one
>   action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and
>   ordered before the second.
>
> If we have two actions x and y, we write hb(x, y) to indicate that x
>   happens-before y.
>
> - ...
> - If an action x synchronizes-with a following action y, then we also have hb(x, y).

So you are safe to access `sharedVariable` knowing that it has (at least) the value written by T1, even without `volatile`.