# Java Thread interrupt() - how fast is it performed?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

How much time does a `Thread` need to stop/disappear after its `interrupt()` method has been called?

Consider the following code:

```
public class MyThread {
    public boolean flag = true;
    public void run() {
        while(flag) {
            doSomething();
            Thread.sleep(20);
        }
    }
}

void foo() {
    MyThread t = new MyThread();
    t.start();
    Thread.sleep(100);
    t.flag = false;
    t.interrupt();
}
```

Does the assignment `t.flag = false;` have any effect? In other words, can a thread exit its `run()` method and terminate "normally" before it is interrupted?

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/130320/5138179)

Comment: flag could be set again on t.interrupt();

Comment: Why do you need another flag? Why can't you use the interrupt flag itself?

Comment: Are you aware that if the call to `doSomething()` in your thread takes a very long time, then your thread will not even be aware that it has been interrupted?

Answer (score 2):

For sharing data one needs `volatile`. Better would be to catch the InterruptedException.

```
public class MyThread {
    public volatile boolean flag = true;
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(flag) {
                doSomething();
                Thread.sleep(20);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to share any data - just wondering if setting "t.flag = false" is redundant code that has no effect.

Comment: You are sharing data between threads: You have a main thread and the thread started in your main method. Both are accessing the variable ... So it must be `volatile`, exactly as this answer tells you. Besides that, catching the `InterruptedException` is the way to go, which indeed could make the `flag` variable redundant.

Comment: You ARE sharing data because t.flag is being modified by one thread and read by another.  You don't have a try/catch around your sleep so your code won't run--therefor t.flag isn't really relevant.  It's use relies heavily on how you catch that interrupt--@Joop's answer is very good at explaining this (In his implementation, for instance, t.flag is unnecessary)

Comment: I don't think `volatile` is necessary here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45269123/1553851

Comment: @shmosel In this case, `volatile` does seem to me to be necessary because `flag` can be referenced before the thread is interrupted.  There's not much of a window for a race condition in the code shown, but it is there.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I guess you're right. That does seem to be the intent of the question.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for worthwile explanation / minidiscussion which adds to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check agains isInterrupted, anhd throw it again since when it returns true it consumes the message.

```
public class MyThread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(!Thread.isInterrupted()) {
                doSomething();
                Thread.sleep(20);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            Thread.interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Making the flag unecessary.

If you want to use the flag and finish the code gracefully you don't need to use interrupt and catch the Exception.

Comment: `isInterrupted()` and `interrupt()` are instance methods.